# track pedestrian with trail using cesium CZML

Tags: cesiumjs, czml

Does someone have a handy example of a CZML file that uses sample properties to track a pedestrian walking a terrain.

I need a billboard at the head of the trail for the person, who will have some custome properties I want to see in the infoblock (about 18K samples).

And my assumption is that a separate id for a path that grows as trace of the path (with the head being the billboard). And this would be in a separate packet, shown as a polyline with material.

and Both would have a epoch for the start and then sample properties for each time step

I.e. the epoch would be today at noon, and the sample properties would be 1 second intervals for each position of the pedestrian which would be duplicated for both the polyline and the billboard.

But is there a better way, and I assume someone has done a sandcastle with an example, right?

Answer (score 1):

I found an example that shows how one can do this more effectively than what I thought (that is you can do this just by adding the data to the coordinates of the billboard as Sampled Data).

https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=CZML%20Path.html&label=